# Remove part of google drive string URL

Tags: ios, swift, string

I have the string below and I would like to remove this part "https://drive.google.com/open?id=" so that my string only has "1FN7S3N_9IAkWYMjLnqh4BKsh8_YT0Zma" Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
let string = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FN7S3N_9IAkWYMjLnqh4BKsh8_YT0Zma"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL could have other parameters so just replacing string might not be a good solution. `URLComponents` comes in handy for this.

```
func getQueryStringParameter(url: String, param: String) -> String? {
    return URLComponents(string: url)?.queryItems?.first{ $0.name == param }?.value
}
```

And use it like this.

```
let string = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FN7S3N_9IAkWYMjLnqh4BKsh8_YT0Zma"
if let id = getQueryStringParameter(url: string, param: "id") {
    print(id)
}
```

Comment: Good solution. The code in the function can be even written in one line: `return URLComponents(string: url)?.queryItems?.first{ $0.name == param }?.value`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Get 2nd component separated by *google drive part*:

```
let string = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FN7S3N_9IAkWYMjLnqh4BKsh8_YT0Zma"
let id = string.components(separatedBy: "https://drive.google.com/open?id=")[1]
```

Replace *google drive part* with empty string:

```
let string = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FN7S3N_9IAkWYMjLnqh4BKsh8_YT0Zma"
let id = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "https://drive.google.com/open?id=", with: "")
```

Comment: @kevinvu yeah, it is a simple solution. But you should understand that the url might contain other parameters, not only **id**. That is why removing a part of string might not be a proper solution. So you should also check the answer by Bilal